# Double value is getting floor-ed when parameter is an Integer

Tags: java, truncate

If i have {"myparam": 12.8} and my request class has
Integer myparam;
myparam gets set to 12 instead of 13.
Why is it a floor instead of a rounding up?

Comment: Why should it round up when you provide a `double` instead of an `Integer`? It's probably worth noting that all JavaScript number types (this looks like JSON) are 64-bit floating bit numbers.

Comment: This is because numbers are usually truncated instead of being rounded when converting to a "less precise" type (ex. double -> integer).

Comment: Nybbit, how do you know that double->integer involves a truncation?

Comment: @stumped Because JSON parsers use subclasses of `Number` internally which involves truncation. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#intValue()

Comment: @stumped that's how the vast majority of programming languages handle the conversion from floating point to integer. It's a bit dense, but the [JLS specifies this behavior](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.4): "*The Java programming language uses round toward zero when converting a floating value to an integer, which acts, in this case, as though the number were truncated, discarding the mantissa bits.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour of requesting an int value from a Double (as seen in the Double API):

```
public abstract int intValue()
Returns the value of the specified number as an int. This may involve
rounding or truncation.
Returns:
the numeric value represented by this object after conversion to type int.
```

The simplest way to explain it - when getting an int from a double, everything right of and including the '.' is chopped of.